# React.js: How to show base64 image with ImageField of react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, imagefield

How to show base64 image with ImageField of react-admin?

I used following code but it is not work:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField, UrlField ,ImageField} from 'react-admin';


export const RequestList = props => (
    <List {...props} >          

        <Datagrid  >
            
           <TextField source="id" />
         
           <ImageField  source={`data:image/png;base64,myBase64Img`}  />
                    
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Thanks for reading everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `ImageField` incorrectly. The `source` property of `ImageField` refers to a key in a record, and this behaves like a pointer in C.

In the following example, the record is `{ id: 123, url: 'cat.png', title: 'meow' }`.
ImageField will lookup a value in the record by key `url` and use that value `cat.png` for the src of the .

#### source

```
import { ImageField, TextField } from "react-admin";
import data from "./data";

<ImageField record={data} source="url" title="title" />
// data = { id: 123, url: 'cat.png', title: 'meow' }
```

#### output html after rendering

```
<div>
    <img src="cat.png" title="meow" />
</div>
```

This demo shows a cat with ImageField in the page.
[ImageField demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-water-u30mn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks you very much for your response. but url key in your example has base64 image value. how to handle it?

Comment: I changed my code to the following code but it is not work yet :   <ImageField  source="myImgBase64"  >
            <div>           
             <img src="data:image/png;base64,myImgBase64" alt="Red dot"/>
           </div>
            </ImageField>

Comment: You've misunderstood the `ImageField`. The `url` in `<ImageField source="url" title="title" />` refers to the `cat.png` in `{ id: 123, url: 'cat.png', title: 'meow' }`, and the rendering result is `<img src="cat.png" title="meow" />` @martin

Comment: Thanks, I saw your result but i can not adapted it for my problem: I receive following result from my remote api: { id: 123, "myImgBase64": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...."}. myImgBase64 key contains a base64 image. how to show it via react? I would really appreciate if  you explain your answer to solve my problem

Comment: See my newly added demo link above @martin

Comment: Thanks you very much. you help me very well. I see that for base64 image is only need to add "data:image/png;base64," at the begining of the base64 string for example: "data:image/png;base64, asdfasfasf....".

Comment: When I open that image in new tab: It set all base64 string in toolbar. There is any way to open image in new tab but dont show all base 64 string?

Comment: Since you offered the base64 string as `src` of image, it indeed shows the base64 string in address bar when you open it. How about wrapping the image in a `<a>` and open another url instead of base64 string when clicked? @martin

Comment: That's a good idea. You mean for example: <a href={''} label="img">
              <ImageField source="url" /> </a> . In this state, it is not open image in new tab and only it can be saved. right?

Comment: Right, when clicked, you can choose to open other url or to do nothing. It all depends on you. @martin

Answer (score 0):

I just throw the base64 string directly in the src field of a img tag instead of using ImageField. Somewhat like this

```
<img src={yourBase64String} title="image" style={{ height: 30 }} />
```